# [Android system/framework -> system/system_ext/framework]How to deal with adding to system_ ext's jar package

Tags: android, extjs, system

The jar package I customize on Android 10 is stored in system/framework.In order to adapt to the modification of system partition, jar is moved to system_ ext.
The previous configuration is as follows.

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += my-framework
PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS += my-framework
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += my-services
PRODUCT_SYSTEM_SERVER_JARS += my-services
```

Now by adding "system"_ ext_ specific "attribute to" jar_ library "to compile the jar package into the system_ ext.
Is there a similar environment variable to fit "system_ext"?

Thank you.